# C# Pass filename as json parameter- Getting error "Unrecognized escape sequence. "

Tags: c#, json

I want to pass a filepath through JSON. On deserializing I am getting error:

> Unrecognized escape sequence. (43): {"Jobtype": "StepBatch","SelectedId": "D:\Input\file1.CATPart"}

I have escaped characters but it still shows error...am I missing something here?

```
string json = "{\"Jobtype\": \"StepBatch\",\"SelectedId\": \"D:\\Input\\file1.CATPart\"}";
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Arguments>>(json);
```

Comment: In json you need double \ characters as values. The actual *value* in the JSON string should be `D:\\Input\\file1.CATPart` so you need to double up each \ character.

Comment: Are you familiar with [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)?

Comment: @itsme86: That just changes the escape character from slashes to double-double quotes.

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from?

Comment: Don't use `JavaScriptSerializer`, it's an obsolete class from the AJAX era with several quirks. Even ASP.NET Web API uses JSON.NET

Comment: @itsme86 the problem is caused by the file path, not the quote characters. JSON is a string so its contents need to contain the escape sequences themselves. To get `\\` into the final string one has to type `\\\\`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the content of your string at execution time is:

```
{"Jobtype": "StepBatch","SelectedId": "D:\Input\file1.CATPart"}
```

That's not valid JSON, because of the backslashes in the value for `SelectedId`. You'd need the JSON to be:

```
{"Jobtype": "StepBatch","SelectedId": "D:\\Input\\file1.CATPart"}
```

so your C# would have to be:

```
string json = "{\"Jobtype\": \"StepBatch\",\"SelectedId\": \"D:\\\\Input\\\\file1.CATPart\"}";
```

However, given that you're immediately *deserializing* the JSON anyway, I'd suggest getting rid of the JSON part entirely, and just creating the `Arguments` values yourself.

If you need to *produce* JSON, create the right values directly, and then get `JavaScriptSerializer` (or preferrably Json.NET) to create the JSON for you, instead of hand-coding it.